# jquery condition with ($(window).width() needs reload effort

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, responsive

I am using a Jquery if else condition with ($(window).width()
 It works fine. But when the window width is changed, the condition is not applied automatically rather I need to reload the browser to apply the condition. What will help to get a smooth CSS media query alike changes when I resize the browser.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $('p').removeClass('blue');
        $('p').addClass('green');
    }
    else {
        $('p').addClass('red');
        $('p').removeClass('blue');
    }
    

});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green
}

.blue {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<p class="blue">Hello World</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/480367f6/)

Comment: You call it on document ready. If you want to check it on each resize, then use `window` resize event... Anyway, checking `window` width to get viewport width is bad practice, use instead [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). And ya, you could just use CSS media queries for that...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Responsive();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    Responsive();
});

function Responsive(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $('p').removeClass('blue');
        $('p').addClass('green');
    }
    else {
        $('p').addClass('red');
        $('p').removeClass('blue');
    }
}
```

Comment: This code seems to work only once, and only one way. May be I am looking for something different. :)

Comment: Responsive function calls when the window width is changed. Control  addClass and removeClass functions. $('p').removeClass('blue') runs everytime. So, P color remains unchanged when the window width is changed. @SalimHossain